# How to install mysql and ruby and mysql/ruby on Mac OS X 10.6.6

Tags: mysql, ruby, macos, osx-snow-leopard

How can I install mysql and ruby and mysql/ruby on Mac OS X 10.6.6? I'm getting this error:

```
 checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no

 ld: warning: in /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.dylib, 
     file was built for unsupported file format which is not the
     architecture being linked (i386)
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing knowledge to the pool! It'd be better though if you formulate it as a question and add the solution as an answer, that makes it easier for others with the same question to find.

Answer (score 1):

Go to http://macruby.org/downloads.html and download and install http://macruby.org/files/MacRuby%200.8.zip.

Go to http://mysql.com/downloads/mysql/ and download Mac OS X ver. 10.6 (x86, 64-bit), DMG Archive.

Go to http://tmtm.org/en/mysql/ruby/ and follow steps to download, then:

1. run command: `ruby extconf.rb --with-mysql-config`
2. modify file "Makefile" in text editor and remove all i386 architecture flags i.e. `"-arch i386"`
3. run command: `make`
4. run command: `make install`
5. run command: `export rvm_archflags="-arch x86_64"`
6. run command: `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib/`
7. run command: `ruby test.rb`
8. run command: `ruby ./test.rb -- [hostname [user [passwd [dbname [port [socket [flag]]]]]]]`

Note:

If you get error like '`libmysqlclient not found`' when testing, you need to specify the directory in which the library is located so that make can find it.

```
% env LD_RUN_PATH=libmysqlclient.so directory make
```

Example:

```
my = Mysql.new(hostname, username, password, databasename)
st = my.prepare("insert into tblname (col1,col2,col3) values (?,?,?)")
st.execute("abc",123,Time.now)
st.prepare("select col1,col2,col3 from tblname")
st.execute
st.fetch  # => ["abc", 123, #<Mysql::Time:2005-07-24 23:52:55>]
st.close
```

Answer (score 0):

Dan Benjamin's Hivelogic is great for this: http://hivelogic.com/articles/compiling-mysql-on-snow-leopard and http://hivelogic.com/articles/compiling-ruby-rubygems-and-rails-on-snow-leopard.  Although Snow Leopard already has Ruby 1.8.7.